# How to have Lotus Notes go to Inbox after log into Windows

Tags: windows-7, boot, lotus-notes

I am trying to setup Lotus Notes 8.5.3 to do the following

- Launch when I log into Windows
- Sign in (my Windows password is the
  same as Notes)
- Go to the Mail tab and go to the Inbox

For the last point I tried following [these directions](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/06/lotus-notes-open-inbox-on-startup.html) but they didn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically start notes on windows start is easy: just drag the lotus notes shortcut to the "Autostart" or "Startup" folder of your start- menu (somewhere in programs) using the right mouse button. When you are there just click on "Create Shortcut" in the menu that opens.
The second thing can only be achieved with the help of an admin: you need to either install the single logon service [troubleshooting here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21304525) using the installationnkit of Lotus Notes, or you need to ask the domino- admin to enable single sign on as described [here](http://de.slideshare.net/We4IT_GmbH/new-single-signon-options-for-ibm-lotus-notes-domino-we4it).

The third one is the easiest one and works exactly as described in your link. Just tell us, what wetn wrong / where you failed...

Additional information: Every database has startup- properties. They can be found pressing the keys "ALT + Enter" when the database is opened.
If the title of the dialog that opens is "Document", then click on that and select "Database". On the fifth tab of this dialog (the one with the "Rocket" or "Pencil"- Icon) you find an option "Restore as last viewed by user". If this is selected, then sometimes databases get "stuck" in a certain folder and always come back to that folder when opened. To reset this behaviour simple untick this option and try to restart the client.

Deleting the "cache.ndk"- file from your Lotus Notes data folder might also help.

Comment: When Notes starts it goes to a folder under folders instead of my Inbox. I followed the steps correctly. Also right when it starts it goes to the home tab but that closes after a second.

Comment: This sounds weird.. Sometimes the "start options" of a database get stuck to a specific folder. You can enter the properties of the database by pressing Alt - Enter and on one tab there is an option "Open as last viewed by user". Uncheck this option, then it will always open to the inbox. Unfortunately I did not understand your other problem. Describe the open tabs after a complete start please. It might be, that in File - Preferences - Windows and Themes you selected to save the window state and that this function goes havoc. Try to disable it

Comment: Ok I'll try again when I'm at work. It's difficult to describe because it seems to change.

Comment: So when Notes starts it goes to the Mail tab but in the mail tab I have created a folder called "customer care" and this is initially selected instead of inbox. Is that clear? If no, how can I be more clear?

Comment: please check the edits in my solution...